# RecyclerView single click not working but works when click twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to receive clicks on `RecyclerView` items for which I am using callback mechanism. I have created `OnItemClickListener` Interface and inside custom Adapter, I have written logic for detecting click with the help of `View.OnClickListener`. But I am getting a callback in myActivity after double clicking any item in the list. Not getting any clue what's happening here!

Code inside Activity:

```
mAdapter = new AppAdapter(this, mAppList, new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {

            Toast.makeText(SelectAppActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});

recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Code For Interface:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}
```

Code for Custom Adapter:

```
public class AppAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    List<App> mAppList;
    List<App> mFilterAppList;
    Activity context;
    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public AppAdapter(Activity context, List<App> appList, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.mAppList = appList;
        this.mFilterAppList = appList;
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_app_list, parent, false);

        final ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,4);
            }
        });
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final App app = mAppList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(app.getmName());
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(app.getmAppIcon());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAppList.size();
    }

    public void setFilter(List<App> appList) {
        mAppList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAppList.addAll(appList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView name;
        public ImageView icon;

        public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onClick ` method is executed on single click?

Comment: sorry!! but did'nt get you

Comment: i mean add a log inside onClick method of `view.setOnClickListener` and check it is calling every time or only on double click

Comment: it is getting called every time on double click

Comment: Why are you writing onClick for adapter's row view if you had already written its itemClick, write any one of them , either onClick or onItemClick and try.

Comment: I am writing onClick on adapter's row to detect click on that row and as soon as it gets clicked I want the callback in my activity with the help of onItemClick

Comment: can you debug and check does this onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,4) get call on first click ?

Comment: try to have class level View.OnClickListener rather than creating anonymous  listener for every new view.

Comment: i got onClick listener in adapter class of recyclerview and in onBindViewHolder itself, no Focus enabled in XML, but when i click it showing toast that is in onClick Event but its not working for setText and update the cell

Comment: @nlogn I am having the same issue,but none of the solutions work for me. I didn't enable focus and clickable in my xml. Can you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 23):

The issue was related to android:focusable="true" in my layout, as I removed this it was working fine,all suggested answers are also working fine.Thanks, all.

Comment: In my case I had `android:focusable="true"` inside the *row_item.xml* and removing it fixed it. Basically, I removed this `focusable` attribute from all xml that was related to the recyclerview *(parent xml, the tag itself, and the child row xml)* and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 14):

If Using RecyclerView in NestedScrollView add this line to RecyclerView :

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: this is working . can you please explain why this is working

Answer (score 6):

There is also a known bug, for those of you who land here check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862910/click-not-working-on-recyclerview-in-coordinatorlayout-when-scrolling) which references [this workaround](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2).

Answer (score 4):

Add these to your parent element of R.layout.item_app_list

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my app I really needed to keep android:focusable="true" so, instead of using a clickListener I'm, using focus listener:

```
            dataItemViewHolder.itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus){
                        System.out.println("onFocusChange");
                    }
                }
            });
```

In my root view:

```
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:clickable="true"
```

You should just know that you will lose click effects and animations.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Click-listener in ItemViewHolder, it works fine.

```
    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public ImageView icon;

    public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //getLayoutPosition is a method of RecyclerView
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,getLayoutPosition());
        }
    });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your onClick in onBindViewHolder and set click as below,
Hope it'll solve your issue....

```
holder.icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,4); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to remove following 2 attributes, if present, from the root layout in the list item XML file

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and it will skip the focusing part, and accept the first touch as Click. No need to go for any workaround

Answer (score 0):

Move your onClickListner from onCreateViewHolder to onBindViewHolder

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final App app = mAppList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(app.getmName());
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(app.getmAppIcon());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v , position);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: careful, if you put the clickListener inside bindViewHolder your clicks will reference wrong positions when views recycle...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue today, your solution may be to just implement this in your gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha04" //latest version to date
```

It's a bug that's been fixed

Answer (score 0):

If Using RecyclerView in NestedScrollView add this line to RecyclerView :

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

it will help you .